# Video won't play (but does upload)

Tags: php, web, video, upload, playback

I have created a website where it's possible to upload video, but the video won't play( once it's uploaded): I have tried everything, but still doesn't work:

Any suggestions?

I have attached the code under her (but I don't think the code is the problem): Do I have to add something in the file "mime"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
</form>


</body>
</html>

<?php 

$name= $_FILES['file']['name'];

$tmp_name= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$position= strpos($name, ".");

$fileextension= substr($name, $position + 1);

$fileextension= strtolower($fileextension);


if (isset($name)) {

$path= 'Hell';
if (empty($name))
{
echo "Please choose a file";
}
else if (!empty($name)){
if (($fileextension !== "mp4") && ($fileextension !== "ogg") && ($fileextension !== "webm"))
{
echo "The file extension must be .mp4, .ogg, or .webm in order to be uploaded";
}


else if (($fileextension == "mp4") || ($fileextension == "ogg") || ($fileextension == "webm"))
{
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$name)) {
echo 'Uploaded!';
}
}
}
}
?>


<?php

if (($fileextension == "mp4") || ($fileextension == "mov") || ($fileextension == "webm"))
{
echo "<video width='1000' controls>
<source src='$path/$name' type='video/$fileextension'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Is `http://whatever-your-domain-is/$path/$name` accessible? Check for browser errors in your developer tools.

Comment: Yes I it's accessible (And I'm able to upload the video, no error), but I just can't play the video :-) (What is developer tools)

Comment: So if you go to the uploaded video URL it shows you the video / downloads the video?

Comment: Yes it does :-) But can't play (including no sound): It's like the website treat it's a picture somehow (weird)

Comment: Hmm, maybe somebody can suggest something else then.

Comment: Yeah it's annoying :-)

Comment: I just looked at at "Open information about web" ->Consol; It says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Add a slash here `$path= 'Hell/';` and remove it there `src='$path$name'`.

Comment: You can write extension check nicer doing `if (!in_array($fileextension, ['mp4', 'ogg', 'webm])) { }`

Comment: Useful info needed for giving an answer... **(1)** What format is the uploaded video and what browser was it tested with? Not all browsers play all your listed formats. **(2)** Provide a testable link to the uploaded video. This way we can check that the upload process isn't corrupting the file somehow.

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your code is making the request for the video before the upload has finished - hence the 404.  IF you can force it to happen after the "uploaded"...

Alternatively - use the file API to play the video locally - without the need to upload to the server (That makes it SUPER FAST too).

Example code: https://github.com/dougsillars/blobUpload/blob/master/playVideoLocally.html